# Bootstrap radio button and label in different lines when label is too long

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, Bootstrap is placing my label in a different line than the radio button ([codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRBPmK)) when the label is sufficiently large:

[image]

Without Bootstrap, the exact same code works as expected, with the label next to the radio button:

```css
* { 
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.choices {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.choice {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio2" value="2"> 
        <label for="radio2">Fusce euismod augue at diam semper congue.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio3" value="3">
        <label for="radio3">Nullam nec ullamcorper justo, at lobortis libero. Praesent congue erat nibh, non tincidunt nisi tempor in. Nam eu mi sed nisl commodo dignissim sed non urna.</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice4">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio4" value="4">
        <label for="radio4">Integer at convallis lorem.</label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

How do I fix with CSS rules? I tried using Bootstrap's `.form-horizontal` and `.form-inline` classes, but that didn't work.

I cannot put the radio button inside the label. Although this will fix the way it is displayed, it breaks some very delicate Javascript somewhere else in the page

Comment: I would create flex rows for the `.choice` elements - this work? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/mwZyQo

Comment: @MichaelCoker That works. I am just slightly hesitant to use flex because of flaky IE support

Comment: Cool, simple layouts like that should work. You can use `display: table/table-cell` instead https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/xroeOR

Comment: Lemme know if you'd like either as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

well I fixed this with just `float`

```
.choices input[type="radio"]{
  float:left;
}
```

```css
* { 
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.choices {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.choice {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.choices input[type="radio"]{
  float:left;
}
.choices .choice4{
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio2" value="2"> 
        <label for="radio2">Fusce euismod augue at diam semper congue.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio3" value="3">
        <label for="radio3">Nullam nec ullamcorper justo, at lobortis libero. Praesent congue erat nibh, non tincidunt nisi tempor in. Nam eu mi sed nisl commodo dignissim sed non urna.</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice4">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio4" value="4">
        <label for="radio4">Integer at convallis lorem.</label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as you add Bootstrap, which was my original problem. My snippet also works without Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Add the .row class to your div. See the example below.

```css
* { 
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.choices {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.choice {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio2" value="2"> 
        <label for="radio2">Fusce euismod augue at diam semper congue.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="choice row">
        
        <label for="radio3"><input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio3" value="3"> Nullam nec ullamcorper justo, at lobortis libero. Praesent congue erat nibh, non tincidunt nisi tempor in. Nam eu mi sed nisl commodo dignissim sed non urna.</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice4">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio4" value="4">
        <label for="radio4">Integer at convallis lorem.</label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

```css
* { 
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.choices {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.choice {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio2" value="2"> 
        <label for="radio2">Fusce euismod augue at diam semper congue.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio3" value="3">
        <label for="radio3">Nullam nec ullamcorper justo, at lobortis libero. Praesent congue erat nibh, non tincidunt nisi tempor in. Nam eu mi sed nisl commodo dignissim sed non urna.</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice4">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio4" value="4">
        <label for="radio4">Integer at convallis lorem.</label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

```css
* { 
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.choices {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.choice {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio2" value="2"> 
        <label for="radio2">Fusce euismod augue at diam semper congue.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="choice">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio3" value="3">
        <label for="radio3">Nullam nec ullamcorper justo, at lobortis libero. Praesent congue erat nibh, non tincidunt nisi tempor in. Nam eu mi sed nisl commodo dignissim sed non urna.</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice4">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio4" value="4">
        <label for="radio4">Integer at convallis lorem.</label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as you add Bootstrap, which was my original problem. My snippet also works without Bootstrap.